# Split google XML items by param value

Tags: xml, filtering, xquery, xmlstarlet

i have one xml file in google vendor standard. There are two language versions of products. I would like to split it into two seperate xml files, keeping file structure. Hard part is, that language info is given only in field **link**  (.pl or .en ).
Two separate files would be great, but one is also fine (I'l just make second run with second condition).

I was thinking of something like this in js (pseudocode):

`file.rss.channel.children.filter(item=>{return item.link.includes(".en")})`

i've tried by xmlstarlet, but with no success

Input file prev:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[ Brand ]]>
        </title>
        <link><![CDATA[ site.link.pl ]]></link>
        <description><![CDATA[  ]]></description>
        <item>
            <g:id>132430</g:id>
            <link><![CDATA[item.link.pl]]></link>
            <g:canonical_link>item.link.pl</g:canonical_link>
        </item>
        <item>
            <g:id>132431</g:id>
            <link><![CDATA[item.link.en]]></link>
            <g:canonical_link>item.link.en</g:canonical_link>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Expected result file:

```
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[ Brand ]]>
        </title>
        <link><![CDATA[ site.link.pl ]]></link>
        <description><![CDATA[  ]]></description>
        <item>
            <g:id>132431</g:id>
            <link><![CDATA[item.link.en]]></link>
            <g:canonical_link>item.link.en</g:canonical_link>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I have no clue how to achieve this, and I will be very grateful for any hints.

Comment: Do you want one or two result files?

Comment: @Cyrus, two files would be great, but one is also fine - I'l just make second run with second condition. Thank You for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT 3.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   
   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
      
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="//item">
         <xsl:result-document href="{tokenize(normalize-space(.), '\.')[last()]}.xml"
                              indent="yes" 
                              cdata-section-elements="title link">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="root(.)/*">
               <xsl:with-param name="this-item" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:param name="this-item"/>
      <xsl:if test=". is $this-item">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
      
</xsl:transform>
```

outputs two result files, en.xml and pl.xml. Here is en.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:c="http://base.google.com/cns/1.0"
     xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
     version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title><![CDATA[
          Brand 
      ]]></title>
      <link><![CDATA[ site.link.pl ]]></link>
      <description/>
      <item>
         <g:id>132431</g:id>
         <link><![CDATA[item.link.en]]></link>
         <g:canonical_link>item.link.en</g:canonical_link>
      </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```